# Loading pdf pages into UIWebView

Tags: ios, pdf, uiwebview

I've loaded a pdf file into a UIWebview using the following:

```
(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];    
    self.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"testScore" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

    [self.webview loadRequest:request];
}
```

This loads the entire pdf into the view. However I'd like a bit more control to be able to load say only page 2 of the pdf file or to next/previous page through the pdf. Can I do this using a UIWebview or do I have to use other means??

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's possible with the default behavior of UIWebView.

You should consider using http://pspdfkit.com/ or something similar.